# How to configure Moq via builder

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, moq

I'm trying out Moq and the builder pattern to set up services for testing CRM plugins. On the builder I have a `ConfigureMock<T>(Expression<Action<Mock<T>>>)` to inject individual configurations. My problem is that once a service is `.Setup()`, I would like to get the entity the service worked on via `.Callback<Entity>()`, but I cannot assign it to a local variable in the test, because I can't do assignments in the callback expression.

Here is the config:

```
private readonly Dictionary<Type, object> MockServices = new Dictionary<Type, object>();

public PluginContextBuilder ConfigMock<T>(Expression<Action<Mock<T>>> setupConfig) where T : class
{
    object svc = null;
    if (MockServices.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out svc))
    {
        var mockSvc = (Mock<T>) svc;
        Action<Mock<T>> setup = setupConfig.Compile();
        setup(mockSvc);
    }

    return this;
}
```

And here's an example how I would like to configure in the test (but will not compile):

```
var createdFanClub = null;
var context = new PluginContextBuilder()
                .ConfigMock<IOrganizationService>(c => 
                    c.Setup(s => 
                            s.Create(It.IsAny<Entity>()))
                            .Returns(fanclubGuid))
                            .Callback<Entity>(a => createdFanClub = a))
```

If I create an additional `Action<Entity>` which does the assignment, it works, but I don't think it's practical, in case I have multiple entities, I will need to make just as many assignments for them:

```
Entity createdFanClub = null;
Action<Entity> assign = a => createdFanClub = a;
var context = new PluginContextBuilder()
                .ConfigMock<IOrganizationService>(c => 
                    c.Setup(s => 
                            s.Create(It.IsAny<Entity>()))
                            .Returns(fanclubGuid))
                            .Callback<Entity>(assign))
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you try to accomplish. If the goal is to have a builder, which has a handle to all the mocks needed, then why not just return the mock itself, and configure it as one normally will do:

```
builder.GetMock<IOrganizationService>().Setup....
```

That will prevent you to chain calls on the same builder (as I see you are trying to do), but it's not a big trade-off, and will simplify your setups.